# Fastest way to see if there any file matching a blob in the tree

Tags: node.js, blob, wildcard, fs, file-exists

I just want to know IF there is ANY file with a given extension in the tree. I'm using node.

For example, I need to know if there is any `.jsx` file in the `src/scripts` directory. Even better if we could do that using blobs/wildecards, like '**/*.jsx'.

I could actually use a blob that would return all the matching files, or I could use some recursion...but, once I just need to know IF there is ANY file matching that pattern, I think there could be a better (more performant) way to do that.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to find a way out.
I did open an issue in the `glob` repository:
https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/356

But, meanwhile, we can use their API with the eventEmitter to abort in the first match.

```
function thereIsAnyFileMatching (pattern, options = {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let Glob = glob.Glob
    let g = new Glob(pattern, options)
    g.on('match', function(file){
      g.abort() // found
      resolve(true)
    })
    g.on('end', function(){
      resolve(false)
    })
    g.on('error', function(err){
      reject(err)
    })
  })
}
```

The only **IMPORTANT** problem here is that, when *aborted*, the "aborted" state is shared. So, if you call it many times in a row, the concurrency may give you false positives, or even worst, never resolving (the "end" even never gets triggered).
So...not a straight solution if you have to deal with concurrency.

The way I turned around concurrency was by using "{...,...}" patterns.
So, for example: `{**/*.js,**/*.jsx}`
In this case, it's just ONE instance of glob being executed looking for any of the patterns. But again...there is a problem :p
It will not tell you WHICH of the patterns matched in the "match" event. You just have to validate it yourself (by checking the file extension, for example).

I hope this helps someone some day :)

Answer (score 1):

I use the package `glob`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob

```
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional 
glob("**/*.js", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames. 
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing 
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"] 
  // er is an error object or null. 
})
```

It may not be the fastest but it is used in over 9,000 other projects.

The way to do this manually would be to read all of the folders and files from the valid path and compare them yourself.

Comment: Yes, I thought so.
This would indeed work, but if I have a huge file tree...there could be a way we would stop the glob loops as soon as it finds the first match.
I might open an issue in their repository on github for such feature :)

Comment: So basically you just want to know if there are _any_ matches and not the entire tree. I think it is a great option and they may be willing to add it.